# Two problems - I am trying to modify the registry but I am getting errors

Tags: registry

Haven't been here in years - but - now here.

Background: I got a virus and had to wipe my hard drive and install Windows 10 (latest version). I must say Win 10 has changed since I bought my USB Stick. (Downloaded latest version and installed that using my key.) So everything had to be wiped and now I'm reinstalling everything. I have run into two problems which are similar.

First problem: When I try to run a batch file to modify the registry I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (da)

S:\Downloads\Utilities\NIR Software\NirCMD>■e
'■e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

"d.bat" is a small batch file which I reduced to these two commands:

```
echo
cls​
```

That's it!

My second problem is I have a registry file which worked under Windows 7. It is:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Open CD/DVD Tray\command]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Close CD/DVD Tray\command]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Open CD/DVD Tray]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Close CD/DVD Tray]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell]
@="none"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Close CD/DVD Tray]
@="Close CD/DVD Tray"
"icon"="imageres.dll,-30"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Close CD/DVD Tray\command]
@="REG_EXPAND_SZ:%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c c:\program_files\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe cdrom close \"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Open CD/DVD Tray]
@="Open CD/DVD Tray"
"icon"="imageres.dll,-30"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Drive.CDROM\shell\Open CD/DVD Tray\command]
@="REG_EXPAND_SZ:%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c c:\program_files\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe cdrom open \"%1\" %*"​
```

When the above runs (this is an alternative to problem #1) what I get is that the "command" line's "(Default)" entry is blank. I have run this as admin and as a user - same result. Ideas? (See image)

Snapshots of registry information from the above script. Note the icons and names get entered but not the command itself.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4an0l91qmf40mj2/2020-08-30_145526.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnizx5vrc39dzc3/2020-08-30_145540.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpzr638sgxsnjsj/2020-08-30_145610.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jc0umvp3zq5q5sp/2020-08-30_145622.png?dl=0

Comment: The batch file was saved in UTF16LE+BOM instead of ANSI.

Comment: Really? I told VIM to save it as a plain DOS file (ANSI). But you are saying it was still UTF8? Werird.

Comment: Not UTF-8. UTF-16LE+BOM. View it in a hex edit and you'll see that the first four bytes are FF FE 65 00. The FF FE are the UTF-16LE BOM. The 65 00 is the letter "e". The FF and FE are interpreted as garbage characters, the 65 is an "e", and the 00 terminates the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The answer to the above questions are : I do NOT know.

After a week where none of the above worked at all, today - all of a sudden - the commands are working. So - I have no idea why they started working but they do.

Yet more weirdness from Windows. Yep. What can I say?